# Trying to use Javascript libraries for my web page, can't understand how to load them in

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create a basic webpage that connects to my MongoDB cluster and adds to the webpage based on the return. The actual scripting hasn't been an issue, but for the life of me I can't understand how to properly load in the library for it to work. I am new to web development, but I also might just be dense. Thanks for your help!

My HTML is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>MRE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div>Header</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and with the line: `import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'`
I get the error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at script.js:1:1)`

Comment: You cannot connect a front-end (web browser) application to MongoDB. It can only be done server-side

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this @Philisonstrike. What do you mean by server-side?

Comment: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/283366)

Comment: Aside from Phil's remark, read the error, which is saying that you are trying to use `import` in a script that you did not tell the browser was an ES module. And while fixing _that_ part won't fix trying to connect to MongoDB specifically (because that's not something you do in the browser), in general when you get that error: mark your script as being a module by using `type="module"` as script attribute.

Comment: Sorry to ask elemental questions, I'm quite new to this sort of programming/development. Is Flask an example of server-side? I don't entirely understand why I can't make a request to my database and then use javascript to add div's as necessary using pure js

Comment: The browser JavaScript runtime environment does not have the capabilities required to connect to services like MongoDB. Yes, Flask is server-side but since you're trying to connect using JavaScript, you might be more interested in using Node.js. The [MERN stack](https://www.mongodb.com/mern-stack) is very popular (but you don't need to use React for the front-end)

Comment: Shouldn't it be forbidden to access a database from the front-end due to security reasons?

Answer (score 0):

you could try importing the script.js like this:

```
<script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
```

the type="module" attribute treats the js file as a module, allowing you to use import/export statements.

Comment: Then I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "mongodb". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: are you sure you've installed mongodb? `npm install mongodb` then `import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';`

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I ran the terminal command again just to make sure and the error persists